# Creating a mapping for a Java class with broken hashcode contract

Tags: java, dictionary, hash

I'm trying to map data to instances of a class which have a broken hashcode contract — namely, for the given class `Foo`,  `fooInst.clone().equals(fooInst)` evaluates to `true`, but `fooInst.clone().hashCode() == fooInst.hashCode()` evaluates to `false`. Furthermore, using the supplied constructor `new Foo(fooInst).equals(fooInst)` actually evaluates to `false`. The class is big, confusing and even denotes a recursive data structure: `Foo` contains mappings to child `Foo` instances. I can't change the class.

**Is there any quick way (regardless of how hacky it is) to create any kind of map-lookup mechanism for these objects?** The structure doesn't contain any circular references, so it should be possible to walk through the structure; Is it possible to e.g. somehow safely "walk" through an object's data fields recursively using reflection and use that to create a hash? Or to avoid hashing for mapping altogether without resorting to e.g. using a `List<Foo>` and a corresponding `List<Bar>` where `foos.get(n)` is associated with `bars.get(n)` and you just search through `foos` until you find an instance equivalent to the one you need to find data for?

Comment: Use your IDE to auto generate a `hashCode` method?

Comment: I don't have control of the class.